# ExtJS 6 plugin.rowwidget Resize row body component on grid resize

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have a grid with [Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.grid.plugin.RowWidget.html). When grid is resized expanded row body components remains with origin width. How I can fix this issue?

As temporary solution I added `resize` event handler as follows

```
            listeners: {
                resize: function (grid) {
                    Ext.each(grid.query('characterPanel'), function (rowBodyComponent) {
                        //if(rowBodyComponent.isVisible()) does not work
                        //rowBodyComponent.updateLayout(); does not work
                        rowBodyComponent.setWidth('100%');
                    });
                }
            }
```

but it seems bad solution for me. Also, it has an issue - all row body components resized regardess of its visibility and in case of many collapsed (after expand) rows may affect performance of my app.

Any ideas?

Here is [simple fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1t5r) illustrating my problem and what I've tried already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an ID to the plugin:

```
{
    ptype: 'rowwidget',
    id: 'rowwidget',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'characterPanel',
        bind: {},
    }
}
```

then you can get the plugin by the given id:

```
grid.getPlugin('rowwidget');
```

This plugin holds a property which is called *recordsExpanded*.
This contains all **internalIds** of the expanded records and the current state of the expansion aswell.

In your onResize-function you can do this:

```
let plugin = grid.getPlugin('rowwidget');
if (plugin && plugin.recordsExpanded) {
    for (let internalId in plugin.recordsExpanded) {
        let record = grid.store.getByInternalId(internalId);
        if (!Ext.isEmpty(record)) {
            plugin.getWidget(grid.getView(), record).setWidth('100%');
        }
    }
}
```

But you should add a delay (at least of 1) to the function call to ensure the resizing is done.

```
listeners: {
    resize: {
        delay: 1,
        fn: function() {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Without the delay, the widget sometimes does not resize after making the row bigger.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, I think you can use `findPlugin()` instead of `getPlugin()`, I prefer to avoid using of `id` if possible. Also I dont get point of using `if(!Ext.isEmpty(record))`, in what case it could be empty?

Comment: Didn't know that `findPlugin()` Thanks! 
The record might be empty if you remove the record, reload the store of if you use a BufferedStore in combination with `purgePageCount`

Answer (score 0):

To add to @xhadon's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43142388/9530790), you can also do the following using a `reference`. Whereby you won't need to check if the plugin exists or it's expanded, since it'll be `undefined` and the function will return.

### View Controller

```
listen: {
    component: {
        '#my-grid': {
            resize: 'onResize'
        }
    }
},

onResize: function() {
    const me = this,
        rowWidget = me.getView().lookup('rowWidget');

    if (! rowWidget) {
        return
    }

    rowWidget.setWidth('100%');
}
```

### View

```
plugins: {
    rowwidget: {
        widget: {
            xtype: 'myrowwidget',
            reference: 'rowWidget',
            bind: {
                store: '{record.children}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```