# Make row expanded element ie extjs grid and chart resizable on window resize

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have used rowExpander plugin in extjs grid on expand of each row 1 property grid with details of row selected and chart is rendered in the div of rowBodyTpl. I want to resize both the elements on window(browser) resize.
`
My parent grid is like this with rowexpander

```
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.app.CustomizedGridPanelv2', {
        width: '100%',
        overflowY: 'auto',
        flex: 1,
        store: this.gridStore,
        plugins: [{
            pluginId: 'expander',
            ptype: 'rowexpander',
            expandOnDblClick: false,
            expandOnEnter: false,
            rowBodyTpl: '<div id="{someId}' + this.id + '"></div>'
        }],
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true,
            deferEmptyText: false,
            emptyText: " No detailsfound."
        },
        columns: [{ columns needed}] });
```

On expand i create a panel and render to the div

```
grid.getView().addListener('expandbody', function(_rowNode, _rec, _expandedHTML) {

        var panel = Ext.create('myPanel', {
            srcPanel: me,
            srcRecord: _rec,
            srcDiv: _rec.get('someId') + me.id
        });

        panel.render(_rec.get('someId') + me.id);


        grid.doLayout();
    });
```

My panel will contain property grid and chart which are the items of extjs panel
`
my parent grid get resized on window resize but the expanded elements get truncated. Is there any way to resize them with browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add `resize` event listener for parent component (grid in your case):

```
listeners: {
    resize: function (grid) {
        var plugin = grid.findPlugin('rowexpander');
        if (plugin && plugin.recordsExpanded) {
            for (var id in plugin.recordsExpanded) {
                grid.getEl().down('.my_row_body#' + id).setWidth('100%');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But actually row body resize with grid out of the box, check [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/213q).

Also you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128075/extjs-6-plugin-rowwidget-resize-row-body-component-on-grid-resize).

If your issue relates to browser window resize, not just grid resize I think you can add `resize` event listener for entire window (not sure its good solution btw):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    myView.doLayout();
}, true);
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for you answer. I tried the solution but in extjs 4.1 for store getByInternalId id not a function. Is there any way of getting record with internalId.

Comment: Actually with ExtJS 4.2 row body resize with grid out of the box, check this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/213q

Comment: In this fiddle i can see the main grid is not resizing its column on window resize. its column get truncated.

Comment: Now it is working as i want my application to work. I want work around for extjs 4.1. also for class "my_row_body" what css you have applied to div?

Comment: Not sure about 4.1 and I dont apply any CSS for "my_row_body" class, its added so we can select required div with `grid.getEl().down('.my_row_body#' + id).setWidth('100%');`

Comment: Thank you. will try some other way.