# Ext JS: How to define layout for rowwidget plugin?

Tags: extjs

I use rowwidget to display extra data for every row in my grid, for example: `panel`, but when I resize my grid or when the grid have a vertical scrollbar the size of the widget (width) remains the same, Is there any way to change the width of the widget automatically?

I mean like a layout for the rowwidget plugin?

```js
config.plugins = [{
    ptype: 'rowwidget',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'panel',
        /* I want it's width as the plugin width even when resizing the grid*/
        items: [],
        height: 50,
        style: {
            'border': 'solid 1px green'
        },
        bind: {

        }
    }
}];
```

[image]

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128075/extjs-6-plugin-rowwidget-resize-row-body-component-on-grid-resize?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: I already read that answer before I posted the question, I want a built-in functionality or override the widget plugin.

Answer (score 0):

the layout can remain the same you can use the width of the grid, or window, to set a relative width for the widget dynamically . there should be a function that returns the width and height after onresize event, something like window.innerWidth , good luck finding the grid body with the console then get its width,

```
grid = Ext.getBody().component.items.items[1].items.items[1].body;
winWidth = grid.getWidth();
```